# Greedy algorithm minimizes the sum

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, contest-math

> There are $n$ positive numbers (not necessarily distinct). In every step, we
> can select two numbers and replace each of it with the sum of the two
> numbers. Prove that in any amount of steps, selecting the two least
> number in every step minimizes the sum of the $n$ numbers.

When the $n$ numbers are different. We assume that they are $x_1,x_2,..,x_n$. We will also assume that at every step two of of $x_i$ has changed its value so there's no need to define other variables. We can characterize every step by only using the indices, so let step $\{a,b\}$ denote changing each of $x_a$ and $x_b$ to $x_a+a_b$. We also used an arrow ($\rightarrow$) to indicate the order of the steps. Let any arbitrary $k$ steps be $\{i_1,j_1\} \rightarrow \{i_2,j_2\} \rightarrow ... \rightarrow \{i_k,j_k\}$. We can finish the problem by showing that by only changing the first step to select the two least number, will result to smaller than or equal sum. I think there will be induction involved here. Any idea?

Comment: Seems to me that a direct proof by contradiction works here. Can you try that approach?

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry. The AM-GM only works for some $k$ and not all $k$. I'll try the contradiction method.

Comment: @CalvinLin May I see your solution? Or at least the sketch of it.

Comment: Can you list out what you've tried? The idea is echoed by Kaind.

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried assuming that it's true for all $\leq k$ moves. At best I can only prove that the sum produced by changing the second, third,.., and $k+1^{th}$ move to pick the minimal is less than the original $k+1$ moves by the hypothesis.

Comment: @CalvinLin Are you sure you have the solution (a fakesolve?) ? I've a complicated solution, but yours sounds elegant.

Comment: Ah, I agree that I had a fake solve. There is a complicated induction approach, which involves showing that we can reorder the steps so that "the first step to select the two least number".